# How to check if the table has rows?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am completely new to PL/SQL. I have written the following PL/SQL script. But it doesn't execute and gives compilation error:

```
set serveroutput on SIZE 1000000;
IF EXISTS (select * from my_table)
begin
dbms_output.put_line('has rows');
end;
else
begin
dbms_output.put_line('no rows');
end;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrong If syntax. And exists not allowed here. Try this way:

```
declare
  cnt number;
begin
  select count(*) into cnt from my_table;
  if cnt != 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('has rows');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('no rows');
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 15):

Anonymous PL/SQL blocks don't start with `IF`. The above code should be in between a `begin` and `end;` at least.

`EXISTS` is an SQL function, it can't be used in PL/SQL like that.

Try something like this:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  c number;
begin
  select count(*) into c from my_table where rownum = 1;
  if c != 0 then
    dbms_output.put_line('has rows');
  else
    dbms_output.put_line('no rows');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Yes, using `EXISTS` in the query is also possible:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  c varchar2(10);
begin
  select case when exists (select * from my_table) then 'has rows' else 'no rows' end into c from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(c);
end;
/
```

Note that both the `EXISTS` and `rownum = 1` version will stop on the first row found, and that's the point, so we don't need to read the whole table/index.

Comment: I like your second solution. There's no point in doing a `count(*)` of the entire table just to determine whether the table has any rows.

Comment: Also, do you actually need to `select count(*) into c ... where rownum = 1`? Couldn't you just `select rownum into c ... where rownum = 1`?

Comment: @Andriy M `select rownum` returns 0 row for an empty table, so the `select ... into` throws an `ORA-01403` error.

Comment: Ah, I see. An equivalent Transact-SQL statement (`SELECT TOP (1) @c = something FROM ...`) would just skip the assignment. I hoped PL/SQL would work the same way. I was wrong then. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: As of Oracle 12, we can also use `LIMIT`.